# TokBox: How resize subscriber video image, always 320x240

Tags: video, tokbox, subscriber

In my client subscriber initialization, I set the video height and width to 100%.  The parent container is set to 366x274 but the video remains at 320x240.  I've tried setting clientSubscriber.element.style.width and height but it just repositions the video in the div.  I put a border around the container and the video is well inside the div.  How do I expand the video to the exact dimensions of the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "fitMode" on both the subscriber and publisher.  The values are "cover" (crop) and "contain" (letterbox).  Contain worked for me.